# Create modal on click react-native android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am Still New on react-native ,

So what I am tried is make a simple app that 
has button when press on it just open alert 
as this Code

```
class MyFirstReactapril extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}> Welcome Nesreen</Text>
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.showAlert}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Myalert</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      )
  }
  showAlert(){
Alert.alert('Fast Donation','', [{text : 'Donate now'},{text : 'add to Container'}])
  }
}
```

Now I want to open Modal on button click not just alert
I tried to read this 
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#content
but I really lost 
how can I make modal using react-native ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal something like below.

```
<Modal visible={this.state.isModalOpen}
       onRequestClose={() => this.setState({isModalOpen: false})} animationType={"slide"}
       transparent={false}>
       <View>
                        //Create your modal view inside this
       </View>
</Modal>
```

In your `showAlert()` method set `isModalOpen` as true in your state.